# How to dock dynamically created UserControl to parent Control in WinForm?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a way to resize UserControls along with parent TabPane ?

**MORE INFO**

I have n number of controls one after an other, each control should be 100px height and width as much as parent control allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties of the `Control` class on your UserControl to define the location and docking inside the parent control. The following link shows how the different settings work by some sample images (although for a TableLayoutPanel, but you will get a good overview):

[Anchor and Dock Child Controls in a TableLayoutPanel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171691.aspx)

**Edit:** For your example, set the preferred size and position of the child control with the designer. Then go to the layout section in the property window and set the `Anchor` property to `Left` and `Right`. This will change the child control's width when you resize the parent control.

Comment: Control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right; did the trick

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) to your form and set [FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection.aspx) to TopDown (and dock it)
2. Add all child controls to that panel

That should be enough.